# C# Replace xml attribute that already exists

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am working on a C# winform project and I am parsing some xml in my application. When i am checking some conditions i am trying to change an attribute value but i get some error. Here is my code:

```
If(mycondition){
 writer.WriteAttributeString("type","loopTask");
}
```

i have to mention that the attribute "type" exists already in my xml file and i get the error 'type' is a duplicate attribute name. How can i replace the value?. What is the easiest way to achieve this task ?.

Comment: Could you show a sample XML file that you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

One way of changing attributes could be:

```
//Here is the variable with which you assign a new value to the attribute
string newValue = string.Empty 
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Root/Node/Element");
node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue;

xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile);

//xmlFile is the path of your file to be modified
```